# combo box and date picker not working in android version of MS word

Tags: android, ms-word, combobox, ms-office, contentcontrol

I have a crucial need to use a Word file with content controls like **Combo Box** and **Date Picker** in the android version of MS Word. However these controls are not working.

here is a Combo box showing keyboard instead of items list
[image]

A date picker content control showing keyboard instead of Calendar:
[image]

I have tried some other apps like WPS Office, Google docs, Docx Reader etc, but none of them worked.

What should I do now? Are there any other apps which support these content controls, or whatever else are your suggestions? Thanks in advance!